# OS independent method to find a file fast with Python

Tags: python, find, platform-independence

With Python, how do I search for a file in a directory (including subdirectories) *fast?*

The standard answers here utilize `os.walk()`, which is slow compared to just calling `find /path -iname "*string*"`, if working under Linux.

Is there a clean platform-independent way to achieve a better speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.scandir` [(GitHub)](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) is faster than `os.walk` and is [now in the Python 3.5+ standard library.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.scandir)